# Add an attribute to an element in an existing XML using Xquery

Tags: xquery, xquery-update, xquery-3.0

I need to add an attribute to an element of my response XML using XQuery. 
Take the below XML as input,

```
<xyz:RootNode xmlns:abc="url1" xmlns:xyz="url2">
  <abc:OtherNodes/>
  <abc:messageHeader att1="val1" att2="val2">
       <abc:childNodes/>  
  </abc:messageHeader>
  <abc:OtherNodes/>
</xyz:RootNode>
```

Need an Xquery that add one more attribute **newAtt** with value **newVal** and give the result as,

```
<xyz:RootNode xmlns:abc="url1" xmlns:xyz="url2">
   <abc:OtherNodes/>
   <abc:messageHeader att1="val1" att2="val2" newAtt="newVal">
       <abc:childNodes/>  
  </abc:messageHeader>
  <abc:OtherNodes>
</xyz:RootNode>
```

Each time the number of attributes of message header may change. So the query should add a new attribute along with all the existing attributes and return the whole document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
xquery version "3.0";

module namespace foo="http://exist-db.org/apps/ns/foo";

declare function foo:process-node($node as node()?, $model as map()) {
    if ($node) then 
    typeswitch($node) 
        case text() return $node
        case element(messageHeader) return foo:messageHeader($node, $model)
        default return element { $node/name() } 
                               { $node/@*, foo:recurse($node, $model) }

    else () 
};

declare function foo:recurse($node as node()?, $model as map()) as item()* {
    if ($node) 
    then 
        for $cnode in $node/node() 
        return foo:process-node($cnode, $model) 
    else ()
};

declare function foo:messageHeader($node as node(), $model as map()) {
element { $node/name() } 
        { $node/@*, 
          attribute { 'newAtt' } { 'newVal' },
          foo:recurse($node, $model)
        }
};
```

You then call foo:process-node on the RootNode

Comment: Hi Loren. Thank you very much for your response. It worked for me! But one more query. If i add namespace to the elements then i'm getting an error messsage as "xyz:rootNode cannot convert to xs:QName". I have updated my question.

Comment: used node-name() instead of name() and changed the code bit.. Its working now. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You can always re-use the wheel that is there for such things, XSLT. Especially if you want to minimise risk in your code.

[eXist supports XSL Transformations](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xsl-transform.xml) and here is an example of how to run an XSLT transformation that does the job that you want:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare function local:add-attribute($input as node()?, $attributeName as xs:string, $attributeValue as xs:string?) {
    let $xslt := <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template xmlns:abc="url1" match="abc:messageHeader">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="{$attributeName}">{$attributeValue}</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
return transform:transform($input, $xslt, ())
};

let $input := <xyz:RootNode xmlns:abc="url1" xmlns:xyz="url2">
  <abc:OtherNodes/>
  <abc:messageHeader att1="val1" att2="val2">
       <abc:childNodes/>  
  </abc:messageHeader>
  <abc:OtherNodes/>
</xyz:RootNode>

return local:add-attribute($input, "hey", "bam")
```

You can also make use of the `$parameters` attribute if you want to bring your XSLT out into its own file. Will make things even more testable and modular.